# How do I get the IP Address of Unauthenticated Minions?

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to find out if SaltStack supports retrieving the IP addresses of Minions that are not yet authenticated (ie `salt-key -L` returns minion ID under `Unaccepted Keys`).  I've looked at the documentation and I do not see anything, but I feel like it should be possible since its reporting a Minion Id from somewhere.

```
salt-key -L --state-verbose=true
```

verbose doesnt seem to provide any additional information either.

Comment: Saltstack uses grains to get minion's information (such as IP address), so that rules out unauthenticated minions. You'll probably have to use some other mechanism (like the one shown in answer).

Comment: The event data doesn't have any transport information either. How minions are connected is completely isolated from everything else.

Answer (score 0):

`salt-key --list unaccepted` will list `Unaccepted Keys`. Now you can use something like `host` to return IP address:

```
for i in `salt-key --list unaccepted | grep -v Keys`; do host "$i"; done | awk '{print $4}'
```

If in the result, instead of IP address you saw `found:`, it means that server is not reachable. So run the command without `awk` to see the more info:

```
for i in `salt-key --list unaccepted | grep -v Keys`; do host "$i"; done
```

Comment: That only works if the minion id is also the hostname.